# Webpage is blinking/showing for a second before loading nicely

Tags: javascript, css, web, squarespace

When loading a webpage, the texts and background-color blink for a short second and then they load properly with the intended animation.

I made a short video to show you what I mean: https://vimeo.com/331182527/bee1d9ad3f [updated, works now!]

Is there any way to put a loading animation so that this doesn't happen? 
What exactly is the problem?
If there is no good solution, is there a way of just making the page completely white for around 0,5 seconds to hide the blinking?

Sadly I am just a self-taught squarespace user, so I dont have any deeper insight into how this could work and I am completely lost.

Header code:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal@4"></script>
<script>

window.sr = ScrollReveal({
    distance: '50px',
    duration: 2000,
    easing: 'ease',
    mobile: true,
    reset: false,
    viewFactor: 0.4,
  });

</script>
```

Footer code:

```
<script>   
sr.reveal('body p',{
    origin: 'bottom',
});

    sr.reveal('h1',{
    origin: 'bottom',
      delay: '1000',
});
</script>
```

It would be very helpful if someone could point to where the issue lies or can solve the problem :)

Comment: hello and welcome to stackoverflow, your video link is 404. Could you also try this : `window.addEventListener('load', function() { /*both header and footer here*/});`and replace comment with your code ?

Comment: Thanks for noticing! I just updated the link, now it works!

Comment: Looks like the background image is loading while you already see the rest of the page. Where do you store your background images? When you fetch them from a CDN and they are quite heavy, this is probably the origin of the issue. Try to store them locally for much faster loading times.

Comment: _“What exactly is the problem?”_ - nothing, really … this is what happens more or less on all websites that simply link between different pages, the browser just doesn’t know what the next page looks like upfront, so it falls back to the default white background color for a tiny bit, before it starts to render the new page. You would have to switch the whole thing to something that does not switch between documents, but uses AJAX to load the content and then replace it in the current document, if you wanted to fully avoid that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information 04FS & Eyk Rehbein!

I will try to use AJAX to load the content to make the experience smoother!